# Why do strings returned by TensorFlow show up with a 'b' prefix in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I just finished installing Tensorflow 1.3 on RPi 3. When validating the installation (according to this https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) somehow a lowercase "b" shown up. See these codes:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# python
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11)
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. Your installation is perfectly fine, this is the normal behavior.

The `b` before the string is due to the Tensorflow internal representation of strings.

Tensorflow represents strings as byte array, thus when you "extract" them (from the graph, thus tensorflow's internal representation, to the python enviroment) using `sess.run(hello)` you get a `bytes` type and not a `str` type.

You can verify this using the `type` function:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(type(sess.run(hello)))
```

results in `<class 'bytes'>` whilst if you do:

```
print(type('Hello, TensorFlow!'))
```

results in `<class 'str'>`

Comment: You're welcome! Remember to accept my response if solved your problem.